# how to animate images in view background

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone.what i need is i have to place a images like stars in the sky and animate the stars glow for example i am showing a sample image how can i done this pls post some code or link regarding this.sorry for my poor English.Thank u in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an animator who can create sequence of star images (png's) with transparency for your desired animation effect, you can just draw them in a view's drawrect over a background image, changing the animation frame to the next one in the sequence during updates based on an NSTimer or using CADisplayLink.  Or you can use CALayers to composite animation layers over a background.  You can also use various core graphics transforms to rotate and scale your star images.

Comment: thank u ur answer is so nice.I am very happy if u post any sample example links